# yq array manipulation returns string literal instead of an array

Tags: yaml, yq

I am currently trying to manipulate a yaml file using yq. For example purposes I condensed it down to the important parts. There is a `keys` variables that I am using to replace the values of `.spec.data`. However, I am getting no the desired result. It creates a string literal for `spec.data` instead of keeping it in array format with its new items. How to achieve the replacement of an array with its new items without turning into as string literal?

**original yaml**

```
spec:
  data:
    - secretKey: VARIABLE_1
      remoteRef: 
        key: VARIABL_1
    - secretKey: VARIABLE_N
      remoteRef: 
        key: VARIABLE_N
```

**curent yaml output**

```
spec:
  data: |-
    - secretKey: NEW_VARIABLE_1
      remoteRef:
        key: NEW_VARIABLE_1
    - secretKey: NEW_VARIABLE_2
      remoteRef:
        key: NEW_VARIABLE_2
    - secretKey: NEW_VARIABLE_N
      remoteRef:
        key: NEW_VARIABLE_N
```

**desires yaml output**

```
spec:
  data: 
    - secretKey: NEW_VARIABLE_1
      remoteRef:
        key: NEW_VARIABLE_1
    - secretKey: NEW_VARIABLE_2
      remoteRef:
        key: NEW_VARIABLE_2
    - secretKey: NEW_VARIABLE_N
      remoteRef:
        key: NEW_VARIABLE_N
```

**code**

```
bashArray=("NEW_VARIABLE_1" "NEW_VARIABLE_2" "NEW_VARIABLE_N")

keys=$(jq -c -n '$ARGS.positional' --args "${bashArray[@]}")

# Create a JSON array of the new data
new_data=$(echo "$keys" | jq -nR '[inputs|{secretKey: ., remoteRef: {key: .}}]')

# # Convert the JSON array to YAML and update the file
new_data_yaml=$(echo "$new_data" | yq e -P -  )

yq e -i ".spec.data = \"$new_data_yaml\"" test.yaml
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Assuming](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/yq/info) you are using [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq), you can use `... style=""` to reformat the YAML code. Also, you can import JSON directly, you can use `env` for easier import through environment variables, and you can use `+=` to append to an existing array:

```bash
# If $new_data is a JSON array
new_data="$new_data" yq e -i '.spec.data += (env(new_data) | ... style="")' file.yaml
```